# How to populate the manager field on Active Directory, using powerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Im trying to populate the manager fields on AD using

```
Import-Csv C:\Testimport.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{Manager=$_.manager}}
```

But I get the following error:

> Set-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception
>   setting " Replace": "Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object." At line:1 char:95
>   + Import-Csv C:\Testimport.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $*.samAcc ountName -Replace <<<<  @{manager=$*.manager}}
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingEx    ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory
>   .Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this issue so far?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the Manager is represented by in your csv you can just use the `Set-Aduser` parameter `-Manager` on its own.

```
Import-Csv C:\Testimport.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Manager $_.manager}
```

If not please show some sample date in your question. This would work in Manager was a account name at least. Also there is an error in the code you ran: `manager=$.manager` should be `manager=$_.manager`

Answer (score 1):

If `$_.manager` is the Manager `sAMAccountName` attribute, you need the `distinguidhedName` attribute to use it later as a value into `-Replace` parameter:

```
Import-Csv C:\Testimport.csv | 

ForEach-Object {

    $managerDN = (Get-ADUser $_.manager).distinguishedName

    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{Manager=$managerDN}
}
```