# Foreach loop only looping 1 time Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

so I'm trying to process improve, and automate new hires......However my foreachloop is not working and for some reason the variables are giving the follow errors

```
Set-ADUser : Identity info provided in the extended attribute: 'Manager' could not be resolved. Reason: 'Cannot find an object with identity: 'Manager Name' under: 'DC=DC,DC=DC'.'.
At C:\Users\ajimmy\Documents\Powershell\Visual Studio\NewHireSpreadsheet.ps1:69 char:5
+     Set-ADUser -Identity $UN  -Title $Ti -Department $DT -Company $CY ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (userid:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityResolutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Set-ADUser : add
At C:\Users\ajimmy\Documents\Powershell\Visual Studio\NewHireSpreadsheet.ps1:71 char:5
+     Set-ADUser $UN -Add @{"EmployeeID"="$EID"}
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (userid:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'TokenExpiryTime' because it is null."
At C:\Users\ajimmy\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_n13adieb.0bj\tmp_n13adieb.0bj.psm1:7395 char:13
+             $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myI ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletInvocationException
```

Here is my code:

```
$Users = import-csv -path "\\Server\Folder\Folder\Folder\NewHire.csv";
    
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -Force;
Import-Module RemoteDesktop -Force;
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -Force;
Import-Module AzureAD -Force;
Import-Module Sqlserver -Force;
    
$OnPrem = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "serveraddress"  -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $OnPrem | Out-Null
    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speak.SelectVoice('Microsoft Zira Desktop')
$speak.Rate = 1.5
    
Connect-ExchangeOnline;
Connect-MsolService;
    
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $department = $User.Department;
    
    switch -Regex -Exact ($department)
    {
        CareCenter {
    
            $FN = $User.FirstName
            $LN = $User.LastName
            $UN = $User.Username
            $PW = $User.Password
            $MN = $User.Manager
            $DT = $User.Department
            $CY = $User.Company
            $EID = $User.EmployeeID
       
            $Email = $User.Username + "@email.com"
            $Ti = $User.Title
     
            New-ADUser `
                -Name "$FN $LN" `
                -GivenName "$FN" `
                -Surname "$LN" `
                -SamAccountName "$UN" `
                -UserPrincipalName "$Email" `
                -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "$PW" -AsPlainText -Force) `
                -Path "path" `
                -ChangePasswordAtLogon 1 `
                -Enabled 1 
    
            Set-ADUser -Identity $UN  -Title $Ti -Department $DT -Company $CY -Manager { Name -is $MN }
            Set-ADUser $UN -EmailAddress "$UN@email.com" 
            Set-ADUser $UN -Add @{"EmployeeID" = "$EID" }
    
            Get-ADUser -Identity "ADTmp-CCRep" -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $UN
    
            Enable-RemoteMailbox -identity "$FN $LN" -RemoteRoutingAddress "$UN@server.mail.onmicrosoft.com"
    
            Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $email -UsageLocation US 
            Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $email -AddLicenses "server:SPE_E3"
    
            break;
    
        }

        Default { write-host ("Department Title Not Found") }
    
    }
```

The Idea is process the spreadsheet and then have it circle each item to find what department its assigned to the create ad accounts, grant adgroups based on a template account and then create onprem mailbox and exchangeonline items. soon i will be adding sql items but i want to get this working first.

Comment: For the manager, if it using a SamAccountName attribute, you need to populate it using the distinguished name. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440241/how-to-populate-the-manager-field-on-active-directory-using-powershell)

Comment: [1] why on  _earth_ are you making those two-letter variables? [that is very very very bad practice, by the way.] you are just introducing a chance for an error. /////  [2] please strop using backticks for line wraps. take a look at `Get-Help about_Splatting` for the recommended way to do what you did with those nasty, icky, yucky backticks. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't accept manager as plain text, try below

$MN = Get-aduser ($User.Manager)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).